# 2 column layout using float and bootstrap

Tags: css, layout, css-float

How to achieve the following layout using bootstarp and float. currently I am using float left and clear:none but some of the divs are not moving up. and there is a space left out. Number of such divs and heights are dynamic.

[image]

Comment: Can you post the code you created?

Answer (score -2):

Here's a little sample of how to get two columns using bootstrap css. You should probably read more [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <h1>1st column</h1>
      </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <h1>2nd column</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```